# R function to join two consecutive names in a vector

Tags: r, loops, vector

I have a vector of characters containing names and numbers, and I'd like to join all the consecutive names together while leaving the numbers untouched. The data is as follows:

```
names_scores <- c("Jake", "Jacobson", "33", "Tim", "Blake", "45", "Muhammad Kamil", "41")
```

I basically want to join the 'split' names into a single string, so the vector looks like this:

```
names_scores_joined <- c("Jake Jacobson", "33", "Tim Blake", "45", "Muhammad Kamil", "41")
```

Note that some names are already joined so those don't need to be touched (like the last one).

Comment: @RonakShah no, the lengths of the names vary from 1 to 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can identify numbers with `grepl` and derive group numbers from the resulting logical vector:

```
names_scores <- c("Jake", "Jacobson", "33", "Tim", "Blake", "45", "Muhammad Kamil", "41")
g <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(grepl("^\\d+$", names_scores)) != 0L))
#[1] 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 6
```

Then we use a group-by function to `paste` the strings together:

```
unname(tapply(names_scores, g, paste, collapse = " "))
#[1] "Jake Jacobson"  "33"             "Tim Blake"      "45"             "Muhammad Kamil" "41"
```

If your vector is long, you should use more efficient group-by functions (e.g., packages dplyr or data.table).